# Changing the opacity of a CSS colour property

Tags: css

I have a CSS property which stores a colour, e.g.

```css
:root {
    --c: #FF00000
}
```

I want to know how I can get the colour stored in the property, and change the value of the alpha channel.

Other posts with a similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72998039/9112181), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50704217/9112181)) have answers saying that the colour property should be defined numerically like `--c: 255, 0, 0`, which then enables the use of `rgba(var(--c), 0.5)`. I want to know **specifically** if there is a way to change the opacity when the colour property is defined **as a colour**.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76330997/8620333